# jquery custom events naming conventions

Tags: jquery, events, naming-conventions

So, what are they?

I mean, I know there is namespacing - but if My event name is too obvious, let say `submit`, then just adding a namespace `submit.myns` doesn't prevents triggering it when standard `submit` is triggered.

Ok, I know, `submit` is quite bad example, but if I want to use same name as some plugin I'm using? When I have big site, with lots of custom events and lots of plugins, this might be a problem, especially if I want to keep event names simple and meaningful.

So do you use some kind of conventions, like prefixes/postfixes (like `myns:event`/`myns_event`)? Or maybe I'm too concerned and my worries are unfounded?

**EDIT :**

Namespaces are great, if you have to group bounded events for easy unbinding. But the way its working, is no way to be sure that handler `click.my` is triggered only by `click.my`. For this, we have to name it different, like `my_click` - then we keep meaningfull name, we have info that it is our event (and it is less probably that someone uses it), and we still can benefit from standard events namespacing.

Some code to see the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/h2kuN/1/

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Namespaces are meant to solve what you're describing. If your namespaces are colliding, they're not specific enough.

Answer (score 9):

**Namespacing solves this problem** — but **only if everybody uses it**.

You can bind to and trigger `christmas.adam` for your seasonal plugin, and I can bind and trigger `christmas.bennett` and we won't interfere. But if somebody comes along and triggers `christmas` then both our plugins will be triggered.

This happens because if you bind a handler to `event.namespace`, then triggering `event` will trigger your handler. This isn't clear in the jQuery API documentation, but it is true as of jQuery 1.7.1.

So (apart from making it easy to unbind many handlers at once), namespacing serves to protect other code, not yours.